# use numpy for query data

Tags: pandas, numpy, sqlite

I have used `pandas` and `sqlite` to perform multiple conditional search in `dataframe`, such like:

```
name    age height
0   john    18  178
1   jen     25  168

age > 20 & height < 170 & height > 150
```

I am wondering if `numpy` can do the same thing, if it can, will it be faster than `pandas` and `sqlite`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `numpy` can do the same maybe and faster than `pandas`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'john', 1: 'jen'},
                   'age': {0: 18, 1: 25},
                   'height': {0: 178, 1: 168}})
print((df['age'] > 20) & (df['height'] < 170) & (df['height'] > 150))
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool


m = df.values.T  # Note the transposition
print((m[1] > 20) & (m[2] < 170) & (m[2] > 150))
array([False,  True])
```

**Performance**

```
>>> %timeit (df['age'] > 20) & (df['height'] < 170) & (df['height'] > 150)
392 µs ± 1.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit (m[1] > 20) & (m[2] < 170) & (m[2] > 150)
6.69 µs ± 12.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: thanks! I supposed the 'df.values.T' is using numpy? I though it will be something like 'numpy.' ....

Comment: is numpy.where() similar to pandas.query()?

Comment: `df.values.T` convert your dataframe to ndarray and transpose the result. np.where and pd.query are not the same. Refer to the documentation.